# How to add the folder of design diagrams in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure-data-studio

[image]

I installed Azure Data Studio recently, but I can not find the diagram folder in the dashboard - how do I add it?

How can I make relationship between entities in Azure Data Studio?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure data studio there is no default folder to generate diagram folder by default. If you want to generate schema diagrams in Azure data studio install Schema visualization extension.

[image]

After installation double tap on database db press "Schema Visualization" on the dashboard.

[image]